# Auto disconnect wifi when out of wifi zone?

Tags: wi-fi, automation

I want my mobile wifi to get disconnect when i am not connected after a specific time. 
 Ex- If i am out of my wifi network for 10min my wifi should get turn off. 
 Note I dont have root access.

Comment: You could use the Condi app to do so, I guess. Google it for more info.

Comment: Have you seen our [automation tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info)? Also worth a look: [WiFi Automatisation](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation)

Answer (score 1):

This is not built-in to Android – so you'd have to revert to an App for it. When just looking for that kind of automation feature, [Smart WiFi Toggler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebouh00.smartwifitoggler) would be worth a look:

> Smart WiFi Toggler is an application designed to control your phone's WiFi using location based rules. Its aim is to conserve battery and minimize data charges by turning WiFi off when not connected to a network, and turning it on when a known hotspot is present. It constantly learns where your hotspots are located to make its decisions.

It's using cell-towers in reach to figure if you're close to a network you're normally using. As long as you have your "cell network" active (i.e. you're not in airplane-mode), your phone knows about those anyway – as it needs that for phone calls, SMS, etc. So it doesn't "waste battery" for GPS or other location stuff. The app initially learns the cells related to your network, so it should be easy to use.

[image: SmartWifi] [image: SmartWifi] [image: SmartWifi]
<sup>*Smart WiFi Toggler* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebouh00.smartwifitoggler); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As you can see from the screenshots, you can also have time-based rules – which might turn out useful for times you want to have "silence" (no incoming calls etc.) and switch to airplane-mode – but want to enable WiFi every hour for a few minutes to check for mails.

For more alternatives, be welcome to see my list on [WiFi Automatisation](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation) – and also check our [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) and [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) tags :)

Comment: The Condi app serves most of such purposes. Do check it out.

Comment: @rjt.rockx why not make your own answer, explaining the details? :)

Comment: I said MOST, not all. For instance, it can switch off Wifi at a particular time, but it can't go too in-depth. It's like a toy car, not a Bugatti Veyron.